# Deadlock on cache table drupal

Tags: caching, database, importing-exporting

My client site has huge data, which they want to download into CSV through View data export module, when multiple users are trying to download the csv file, its resulting in an error.

In log messages I can see error like-

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction:
```

When I am trying to see my innodb status through:
 mysqlengine innodb status\G;
its showing deadlock for insert into cache table.

Can anyone help in this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get rid of Deadlocks and Lock time out type issues?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/108588/how-to-get-rid-of-deadlocks-and-lock-time-out-type-issues)

Comment: Also, consider moving caches to memcached or similar solution.

Comment: @Shawn Conn, I have already checked that post, tried that, I am getting error while applying patches mentioned in the link contained in that post. Any other way?

Comment: Drupal 7.22 ? If that's indeed your Drupal version, then forget whatever you're working on ... and go find out what was Drupal 7.32 all about ... and upgrade to a more recent Drupal version ...

Comment: It cant be done now as it can cause various other problem in live environment, is there any other solution to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.drupal.org/project/apdqc is a pretty good solution for the issue you're describing. Install the module and go to the status report page (`admin/reports/status`); it will then run a gamut of tests and give you advice on things to change in your settings.php, php.ini, and my.cnf files.

The root cause of most of the cache deadlocks is that a truncate query and insert query are in conflict with each other.

Comment: The same answer was posted under question marked as potential duplicate...

Comment: @mikeytown2 I have seen that module, its available in beta version, as far as I know its not suggestable to use beta version in production site. will it be ok to use it in live environment? will it be ok to use it with Drupal 7.22?

Comment: @user First step is to upgrade drupal to the latest version. A lot of deadlocks where fixed in [7.25](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-7.25-release-notes) and a massive security hole was fixed in [7.32](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-7.32-release-notes). I use the apdqc beta in production without issues. There are some edge cases that need to be addressed in it before the 1.0 version is out.

Comment: @mikeytown2, I have upgraded my Drupal version, installed apdqc module, I have converted  Cache table collations and  Cache table indexes still I am seeing those in my status report, moreover I tried to enable mysqli extensions on my server but unfortunately I couldn't find a relevent place or way to enable them, can you guide me on that as I can see deadlock on cache_menu table and multiple users are not able to download csv report.

Comment: I have enabled the extensions, no more operations to do, but the problem is when multiple users try to download the csv report simultaneously then it will result in white screen.

Comment: @user turn on error reporting so the error that is causing the white screen is known. Also look into using this patch so any errors output a lot more info https://www.drupal.org/node/1158322#comment-9487545

Comment: @mikeytown2  I enabled error reporting, applied the above patch, I can see error _"Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/html/code/xxx/includes/database/database.inc on line 940"_, I will change max_execution_time limit.
Another thing which I noticed when I tried to see my innodb status is **Deadlock on semaphore table**.

Comment: @mikeytown2 I have set **max_execution_time** to 0, now multiple users are able to download the report but its taking long time, another thing is now there is no deadlock on semaphore table but I can see it on cache table, its a convoluted situation.

Comment: @user-pj The [devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) has a query log; go to `admin/config/development/devel` and check "Display query log" and switch the "Sort query log" to "duration". Be sure to use the latest dev of devel; fixes an issue with the views module when using the query log. This should show what query is taking a long time, from here a solution to your problem can be found.

Comment: @mikeytown2, now deadlock problem is solved, thanks a lot,only problem is site is running slow, I will check that with devel module, one more question is, can we use this module with Memcache?

Comment: @user-pj devel and apdqc are both compatible with memcache. Devel will not output memcache get/set times and apdqc will not prefetch the memcache cache bins.