# deadlock with cache clear

Tags: caching

I am trying to clear the cache or view status reports in D7 i get the below error.

PDOException: SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction: DELETE FROM {cache_bootstrap} WHERE (cid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => system_list ) in cache_clear_all() (line 167 of /var/web/includes/cache.inc).

How do i fix the serialization error?

Thank you..

Comment: I restarted mysql server. I still see a different error.                                            PDOException: SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction: DELETE FROM {cache} WHERE (cid LIKE :db_condition_placeholder_0 ESCAPE '\\') ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => node\_types:% ) in cache_clear_all() (line 167 of /var/web/includes/cache.inc).

Answer (score 2):

The [Asynchronous Prefetch Database Query Cache](https://www.drupal.org/project/apdqc) module should handle it. If you want the longer version see [How to get rid of Deadlocks and Lock time out type issues?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/108588/how-to-get-rid-of-deadlocks-and-lock-time-out-type-issues/108673#108673)